# Rebuild checkout page in opencart on passing registered email as querystring to checkout/cart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a requirement to rebuild checkout page, containing latest abandoned products.

If you are already logged into opencart consumer site and hit this url  - http://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart, it will definitely list all products in cart ( that are yet to be purchased).

Without logging into consumer website, if someone directly hits this url - http://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart&email=someone@example.com - it will list all products that are yet to be purchased by `someone@example.com` (also known as `abandoned products/cart`), provided `someone@example.com` is a registered user of opencart website.

I want to pass that email address from the url as a querystring to the checkout/cart page and use that to return abandoned products for that customer email.

How can I take that email in checkout/cart page and show the user the abandoned cart products?

I am very much new to `opencart`, i don't know much about core functionality, so i searched how to achieve this, but landed with extensions ( such as [THIS](http://isenselabs.com/products/view/abandonedcarts-proved-recover-abandoned-cart)) that are paid, my requirement is to have it build within URL, that i explained above.

**Provided** : `Opencart` installation is a stock version, no other addon/plugins are installed.

**EDIT**

I have tried following.

```
if(isset($this->request->get['email'])) 
{ 
    $email = $this->request->get['email']; 
    $cart_details = $this->db->query("SELECT cart FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c where c.email = '" . $email . "'"); // just for tesing, i will fix this to prevent SQL injection.
    $this->session->data['cart']= $cart_details->row['cart']; 
}
```

when i do echo with `"$cart_details->row['cart']"`, it got required value, but even after setting that value to `session` checkout page is not rebuilding list of abandoned products.

Comment: Why is this tagged by **opencart** and also **magento**? I think you should stick to one platform only in your question to avoid it to sound as *too broad*. In OpenCart I cannot think of any **cart id**, the only think you would need is the **customer id** as the contents of one's cart (that wasn't yet *checkouted*) should be stored in the database in the `customer` table (as a serialized array). Please, notice that it's **I** and not **i** if you want to speak in first singular person.

Comment: I have changed wording edits, and removed Mangeto Tag, but should i  have to store customer's cart( that was not checkedout) in DB as serialized array?

Comment: In OpenCart, this should already happen. If not, you can do this by yourself. There is already a column `cart` in the `customer` table.

Comment: So let's say, I am going to add some code to catalog\controller\checkout\checkout.php, and if i get email in query string parameter, can I set required variables ( like sessions/cart details) , so that checkout page will behave like user has already logged into the system and going to see the payment page. Is that possible using php code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you know user's email address you can check that such user exists in your DB and then retrieve it's cart contents as well as act as if he already logged in. You would need to load the contents of the cart into session of course as the whole checkout process is relying on session data only.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to implement this.

Comment: I have tried this, but it is breaking the page, I have directly assigned to cart session , and then used json_decode, but still it is breaking page, I think, there is something more need to be set to get it work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not see any code.

Comment: I am using following code, but it is not working. 

if(isset($this->request->get['email'])) 
{ 
$email = $this->request->get['email']; 
$cart_details = $this->db->query("SELECT cart FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c where c.email = '" . $email . "'"); 
$this->session->data['cart']= $cart_details->row['cart']; 
//return; 
}
when i do echo with " $cart_details->row['cart']", it has got required value.

Comment: **1.** SQL injection; **2.** Calling SQL query from the controller code; **3.** How is `$this->session->data['cart']` used afterwards? **4.** Maybe you wanted to do `$this->data['cart'] = $cart_details->row['cart'];` and then use it as `$cart` variable in the template...?

Comment: I found the solution, I have to decode to some specific format, before assigning that to session, so this is working fine, but one concern is, is it secure enough?Because, anyone can pass any email to see checkout products.

Comment: Your solution, if it is still the same as in your comment above, is completely insecure! Not only everybody can see content's of other's cart (if he knows their email address), but imagine somebody would insert an email as this one: `'; DELETE FROM customer`...

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was asking is there a way ( so finally there is way, but insecure!).

Comment: @Downvoter - how to improve this question to get UpVote?

Comment: *so finally there is way, but insecure* - this is entirely not true! Only your solution is insecure, because you are not escaping the dynamic value for SQL query. Also you are ignoring the MVC pattern and calling a SQL query from the controller code.

Comment: No, i have fixed this, used prepared statement , since i am passing email only, i am also validating email format, then i do SQL query, so i think it is 100% SQL injection proof,and also i have structured my code to follow oepncart coding convention ,any further thoughts?

Comment: Dear downvoter, please leave a comment to help me in improving my question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have changed checkout/controller/checkout/cart.php index method, and added a check to see if the custom url contains "cmail". Then I validate the email address supplied in the url. At this point, I query the DB to get the customer's "cart" column ( note i have used `escape` to prevent SQL injection), which is then decoded and put into session. If you hit the site with the url "localhost/index.php?route=checkout/cart&cmail=some@domain.com", you will get the cart rebuilt in the page. I have used following code.

```
if(isset($this->request->get['cmail']))
{
    $email = $this->request->get['cmail'];  
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $cart_details = $this->db->query("SELECT cart,customer_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "'");

         if($cart_details->num_rows > 0)
         {
             $cart_data = $cart_details->row['cart'];
             if ($cart_data && is_string($cart_data)) {
                 $cart = unserialize($cart_data);

                 foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
                    $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = $value;
                 }          
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is Off Topic and this answer gives no more light on the topic even for the users seeking for the same question - but raises more questions on the other hand. Either delete the whole question or add your whole solution (with code that has been added, **not the whole classes/files**) in kind of tutorial.

Comment: @shadyyx, i have updated my question as well as posted answer, please review it and give me necessary feedback and also help me to post better question keeping this question as example! That will be a lot help for me.